# Does Docker HEALTHCHECK disable container networking when unhealthy?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, health-check

I need some clarification in regards to using HEALTHCHECK on a docker service.

Context:

We are experimenting with a multi-node mariadb cluster and by utilizing HEALTHCHECK we would like the bootstrapping containers to remain **unhealthy** until bootstrapping is complete. We want this so that front-end users don’t access that particular container in the service until it is fully online and sync’d with the cluster. The issue is that bootstrapping relies on the network between containers in order to do a state transfer and it won’t work when a container isn’t accessible on the network.

Question:

When a container’s status is either **starting** or **unhealthy** does HEALTHCHECK completely kill network access to and from the container?
As an example, when a container is healthy I can run the command `getent hosts tasks.<service_name>`
inside the container which returns the IP address of other containers in a service. However, when the same container is unhealthy that command does not return anything… Hence my suspicion that HEALTHCHECK kills the network at the container level (as opposed to at the service/load balancer level) if the container isn’t healthy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran some more tests and found my own answer. Basically docker does not kill container networking when it is either in the **started** or **unhealthy** phase. The reason `getent hosts tasks.<service_name>` command does not work during those phases is that that command goes back to get the container IP address through the service which does not have the unhealthy container(s) assigned to it.